# Suspend function inside a Coroutine with delay is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following Coroutine which calls a suspending function, adds a delay afterwards and displays the result to user

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
   //some initial setup

   val result = service.getResult() //suspend function

   //add a delay of 1s
   delay(1000)

   when(result) {
      ERROR -> {
         Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      } 
      //other conditions
   }
}
```

When I add the delay, the code under it never runs. Being a suspending function, delay should work and then rest of the code has to be executed. Not sure what has gone wrong. Any clue?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the `delay` line? Are you sure `getResult()` is ever returning?

Comment: Yes, `getResult` returns correct values. And if I remove / comment out `delay`, it works all OK

Comment: What if you replace `delay(1000)` with `yield()`? This is weird. I've never seen `delay` affect the behavior of code execution. Is it possible you imported a different `delay` function than `kotlin.coroutines.delay`?

Comment: Me neither, quite surprised to be honest! It works with `yield` though

Comment: In that case I would add the delay inside `getResult()`

Comment: This is very surprising. Have you tried wrapping try-catch around the delay?

Comment: I just encountered the same where `kotlinx.coroutines.delay(2000)` in a mock `suspend fun` never returns. Trying to `catch (e: Exception)` around the delay caught nothing.

Comment: In my case adding the code block with `delay()` inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){}` solves the issue.